# Errors in Arduino CAN example receive_check in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino

I have loaded the "receive_check" [Arduino CAN example](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/blob/master/examples/receive_check/receive_check.ino) from **Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield**, and right away Visual Studio displays two warnings in one of the calls the example makes.

[image]

Both warnings say

```
argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "byte *
```

The code compiles just fine. If I change the `unsigned char` to `byte` the warnings vanish.
(I get no such warning/error message when opening this example in the Arduino IDE.)

My questions:

- Is there generally a reason to have [declaration](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/blob/master/mcp_can.h#L128) and
  [implementation](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/blob/master/mcp_can.cpp#L889) with different (argument types) method signatures?
- Why does VS underline the code yet compiler is not bothered by anything?
  (Does it have something to do with how the **INT8U** is defined in
  [mcp_can_dfs.cpp](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/CAN_BUS_Shield/blob/master/mcp_can_dfs.h#L59)? Does VS not know `char` is basically `byte`?)

Comment: *Does VS not know char is basically byte?*  Please verify what `byte` is, as that is not a C++ type.  And to verify, if you have `foo(byte); foo(char);` does Visual Studio consider them as different functions?  If they are not different, you would get an error that you're defining the function twice.